# Clear overrides without changing current font style (Character Style mainly) in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have been trying to figure out the correct approach to clear overrides without changing current font style in InDesign.

I have read the InDesign Guide in helpx.adobe.com but ain't able to find a suitable approach to do so. Whenever I clear override, both the "Character" and "Paragraph" styles gets applied to the set attribute. For example: If there is an italic word included in override styles, after clearing the override, the word gets changed to regular style. I can't let this italic word to get affected.

Hope, I have explained my problem well enough. If anyone needs more clarification or facing the same problem, please reach out to me.

Thanks,
Raaj Kanchan

Comment: Some clarification is in order here, I think; your question is not very clearly worded. How is the italic applied to this italic word? Is it a character style that specifies it as italic, or are italics manually applied? If the latter, how would you expect InDesign to maintain this particular manual override when removing manual overrides? This is exactly why you should generally use styles to format things, rather than manual overrides.

Comment: Hello Janus Bahs Jacquet,

Answer (score 1):

Possibly helpful... Not sure though.

Assuming the paragraph style appears listed with a + symbol, such as `Style+`. Which indicates that some alterations have been made to the local text in general which are not the same as the style specifies....

You want to remove any of those local variations, but **not** remove Character styles which may be applied within the text.

Then....

---

**Rather than using `clear overrides` merely insert the cursor and <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-click the Paragraph style again, in the Paragraph Styles Panel**.

---

The Option/Alt+click will remove any non-style setting but will **not** remove overrides. Basically it **resets** the text to the *Paragraph Style* so it matches the settings of that style while not changing any applied internal Character styles - in short **reset text to Paragraph style but retain overrides**.

[image]

Be careful, option+*dragging* a style in the Paragraph Styles Panel will *duplicate* the style, So be sure to just click, don't drag.

Comment: Hello Scott,

Thanks for creating this GIF to explain your answers in detail. Wish I should have created the same creativity to describe my question. 

Thanks for sharing the tip too. I will certainly use it, when I come across this problem again. Thanks again for helping me.